# SSH - Loop through lines from txt file and delete files

Tags: ssh, cron

I have a .txt file and on each line is a different file location e.g.

```
file1.zip
file2.zip
file3.zip
```

How can I open that file, loop through each line and rm -f filename on each one?

Also, will deleting it throw an error if the file doesn't exist (has already been deleted) and if so how can I avoid this?

EDIT: The file names may have spaces in them, so this needs to be catered for as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with `cat` to iterate through the lines:

```
IFS=$'\n'; \
for file in `cat list.txt`; do \
    if [ -f $file ]; then \
        rm -f "$file"; \
    fi; \
done
```

The `if [ -f $file ]` will check if the file exists and is a regular file (not a directory). If the check fails, it will skip it.

The `IFS=$'\n'` at the top will set the delimiter to be newlines-only; This will allow you to process files with whitespace.

Comment: Is the if [ -f ] check necessary? rm -f will not immediately fail on either a nonexistent file or a directory (just a diagnostic message), and it won't remove directories.

Comment: @Kiyura The OP asked on how to avoid throwing an error; the conditional check will, for all purposes, avoid throwing any errors (if the file doesn't exist, or if it's a directory).

Comment: I understand "throwing an error" as something that actually causes the command to fail. If you rm -f [some list of files], it will print a message for each directory and unfound file, but it will also continue and delete everything it can on the list. Your check doesn't add any functionality, it basically just preempts those messages, and adds the overhead of running the command individually on each file. If you really want to eat the error output it would be better to do that explicitly.

Comment: My bad, it actually won't print anything for unfound files, but it also won't fail.

Comment: @Kiyura There is a difference between an error message displaying, and one causing a crash. Many people who depend on application-output would prefer to not include verbose output as it can be seen as "noise" whereas a "real error" would still display, though I'm not here to debate the OP's intentions. If you dislike my answer so much, please downvote it (though it works perfectly fine).

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, because it does work, and it's not like the "overhead" actually matters. I'm just pointing out why I would go with something simpler than a bash script (like my answer). By the way, to eat stderr: `rm -f [file list including directories] 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Having the file exists check is fine and may be for the best. As with the other answer, I forgot to mention that the file names may have spaces and this doesn't seem to cater for that. How could I make it do so?

Comment: Afraid not, I am testing will the following files: "file1.zip" (which gets removed), file1 - Copy.zip, file1 - Copy (2).zip and file1 - Copy (3).zip. The latter 3 do not get removed.

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop Updated answer with using `IFS`; this will specifically declare the delimiter to be used as a newline.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks alot. Can you explain exactly what IFS does?

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop `IFS` stands for `Internal Field Separator` and is an internal variable for bash. It is used, by bash, to determine the word-boundaries for interpreting strings. By setting it to `\n`, a "word" is a full line of text; by default `IFS` is set to all whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines).

Comment: I thought it might be something like that, is it okay to leave it set to \n within a single .sh script then? Or would it be safer to set it to a space again afterwords? I'm guessing it doesn't really matter, but being more accustomed to PHP, I don't tend to change the internal variables just for one little thing!

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop Honestly, I've never had issues with changing it with a single script - but I don't know if it actually affects the environment or not. You can be "on the safe side" and set it to a temporary variable and then replace it when done: `SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS='\n'; ...code...; IFS=$SAVEIFS;`

Answer (score 0):

`xargs -n1 echo < test.txt`

Replace 'echo' with rm -f or any other command. You can also use `cat test.txt |`

'man xargs' for more info.

Comment: Is the n1 supposed to seperate by line? There may be spaces in the file names and it seems to be deperating by space.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does separate by spaces. You could pipe it through sed first to wrap each line with quotes, or do it on the file itself with vim. Sed option: `cat test.txt | sed -e "s,[^.],\'&," -e "s,\$,\'," | xargs -n1 echo` EDIT: Never mind, I just tested and this doesn't work either. xargs doesn't handle spaces well.

Comment: As a side note, a more robust option for this whole task would be using find -print0 to get all the files you want, in conjunction with xargs -0. I don't know how you're getting your input file, though.